# glibc error detected no idea what is wrong

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
//#include<mathscall.h>
#include<time.h>
#include"plot.h"

int main()
{
    int no_packets = 10000;
    //float lamda = 0.1;
    double lamda = 0.1,*lamdas;
    int i,j,cumulative_X,count = 0;
    int trans_time = 1;
    double temp,*throughput;
    int iterations = 1/0.1;
    printf("Iterations: %d\n",iterations);
    throughput = (float *)malloc(iterations*sizeof(float));
    lamdas = (float *)malloc(iterations*sizeof(float));
        int *pkt_collision;
    double *pkt_holder;
    int k=0;
    float p;
    for(p=0.1;p<1.1;p=p+0.1)
     {
        lamdas[k]=p;
         printf("lamdas: %f\n",lamdas[k]);
         k++;
        //printf("k: %d\n",k);
     }
    int l=0;

    while(lamda<1.1)
    {
         count = 0;
         temp = lamdas[l] * no_packets;
         int avg_packets = (int)temp;
         //printf("In here\n");
         pkt_holder = (double *)malloc(avg_packets*sizeof(double));
         pkt_collision = (int *)malloc(avg_packets*sizeof(int));
         //temp = lamda * no_packets;
         //printf("In here\n");
         srand(0);

         for(i=0;i<avg_packets;i++)
         {
            pkt_holder[i] = 0.0;
            pkt_collision[i] = 0;
         }

        for(i=1;i<avg_packets;i++)
        {

              double X;
              do
              {
                X= (rand() % 10000) / 10000.0;

              }while(X == 0);

                  double time_temp = -(double)log(X)/lamda;
             //printf("i: %d\t time_temp: %f\n ",i,time_temp);
              pkt_holder[i]=pkt_holder[i-1] + time_temp;

}



for(i=1;i<avg_packets;i++)
{
             for(j=i;j<avg_packets;j++)
             {
                if((pkt_holder[j]-pkt_holder[i-1])<=5 &&pkt_collision[j]==1)
                {

                     pkt_collision[j] = 1;
                     pkt_collision[i-1] = 1;
                 }
                 else
                    break;
            }
        }

for(i=0;i<avg_packets;i++)
{
             if(pkt_collision[i] == 0)

             {

                count++;
             }
 }
        throughput[l] = (float) count/no_packets;

        lamda+=0.1;
    free(pkt_holder);
        free(pkt_collision);// glibc error occuring after execution of this //statement
        l++;
 }


 printf("Sucess: %d\n",count);
 return 0;
}
```

In this program I am trying to simulate throughput of pure aloha.

Beginning from `lamda  0.1` to `lamda = 1`, I am trying to find the throughput corresponding to these values.

In while loop I am trying to reallocate the size of both pkt_holder and pkt_collision in each iteration by freeing their memory at the ending of each iteration of loop.

When I tried to debug in eclipse it is showing glibc error when free(pkt_collision) is executed.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: `lambda` and `thoughput` should be float* you have double*. Do `lambda[k]` cause problem accessing invalid memory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect that you are overwriting something in the following sequence:

```
lamdas = (float *)malloc(iterations*sizeof(float));
    int *pkt_collision;
double *pkt_holder;
int k=0;
float p;
for(p=0.1;p<1.1;p=p+0.1)
 {
    lamdas[k]=p;
     printf("lamdas: %f\n",lamdas[k]);
     k++;
    //printf("k: %d\n",k);
 }
```

You allocate `iterations` slots for `lamdas`, but when you iterate, you don't iterate with an integer index, but with a floating point index. Thus you might get one more iteration than you think (this has to do with inability to represent `0.1` exactly in floating point).

The solution is to write

```
for(int k = 0; k < iterations; k++) {
  lamdas[k] = 0.1 * (k+1);
  // etc
}
```

Since the pointer `*pkt_collision` is stored right after `lamdas`, and since most compilers store some information required for `free` right before the pointer (this is not by standard, but this is my experience), writing past the end of the allocated space for `lamdas` does, in fact, write exactly into the space that is used by `free`.

I think this will solve it.

**EDIT** just noticed that you are declaring `lamdas` as `double*`, but casting the pointer to it as a `float*`. Didn't you see the compiler warning?

**ALWAYS ENABLE COMPILER WARNINGS, AND HEED THEM**

So you have two problems. You need to allocate enough memory:

```
lamdas = malloc(iterations * sizeof(double));
```

and use an integer as your loop variable.

As an aside, you can prevent this problem in future by writing

```
lamdas = malloc(iterations * sizeof(*lamdas));
```

This way you don't have to remember what type it was - the compiler will know, and get it right.

**UPDATE**
Compiling your code with `gcc -Wall` gives:

```
temp.c:16:16: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'double *' from
      'float *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    throughput = (float *)malloc(iterations*sizeof(float));
               ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
temp.c:17:12: warning: incompatible pointer types assigning to 'double *' from
      'float *' [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
    lamdas = (float *)malloc(iterations*sizeof(float));
           ^ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
temp.c:12:9: warning: unused variable 'trans_time' [-Wunused-variable]
    int trans_time = 1;
        ^
temp.c:11:13: warning: unused variable 'cumulative_X' [-Wunused-variable]
    int i,j,cumulative_X,count = 0;
```

The answer is right there in front of you. It is a REALLY good idea to compile with all warnings enabled, and improve your code until all warnings are gone. This is just one more example of why that is true.

**FINAL(?) edit**

I found a few more inconsistencies in your code. Here is the complete, working version.

A few things to note:

- to get a random number between 0 and 1 (not including 0) probably the best thing to do is:

`(rand()+1.0)/RAND_MAX`

Using the `%` operator will give you a non-uniform distribution (greater chance of smaller numbers - try it and you will see).

- you test for a `collision` flag being set when you look for collisions - this means no collisions will be found / counted (you only allow collisions with packets that have had collisions...)
- I made some changes in the code according to the things I mentioned above
- I added some `printf` statements
- I fixed some formatting / indentation

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

int main()
{
  int no_packets = 10000;
  double lamda = 0.1,*lamdas;
  int i,j,cumulative_X,count = 0;
  int trans_time = 1;
  double temp,*throughput;
  int iterations = 1/0.1;
  printf("Iterations: %d\n",iterations);
  throughput = malloc(iterations*sizeof(*throughput));
  lamdas = malloc(iterations*sizeof(*lamdas));
  int *pkt_collision;
  double *pkt_holder;
  int k=0;
  float p;
  for(k=0; k<iterations;k++)
  {
    lamdas[k]=0.1*(k+1);
    printf("lamdas: %f\n",lamdas[k]);
  }

  int l=0;

  while(lamda<1.05) // to avoid rounding errors
  {
    count = 0;
    temp = lamdas[l] * no_packets;
    int avg_packets = (int)temp;
    pkt_holder = (double *)malloc(avg_packets*sizeof(double));
    pkt_collision = (int *)malloc(avg_packets*sizeof(int));
    srand(0);

    for(i=0;i<avg_packets;i++)
    {
      pkt_holder[i] = 0.0;
      pkt_collision[i] = 0;
    }

    printf("lamda = %.1f; avg_packets = %d\n", lamda, avg_packets);
    int totalTried = 0;
    for(i=1;i<avg_packets;i++)
    {
      double X;
      do
      {
        //X = (rand() % 10000) / 10000.0;
        X = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
      } while(X == 0);

      double time_temp = -(double)log(X)/lamda;
      pkt_holder[i]=pkt_holder[i-1] + time_temp;
    }

    for(i=1;i<avg_packets;i++)
    {
      for(j=i;j<avg_packets;j++)
      {
        if((pkt_holder[j]-pkt_holder[i-1])<=5) // &&pkt_collision[j]==1)
        {
          pkt_collision[j] = 1;
          pkt_collision[i-1] = 1;
        }
        else
          break;
      }
    }

    for(i=0;i<avg_packets;i++)
    {
      if(pkt_collision[i] == 0)
      {
        count++;
      }
    }
    throughput[l] = (float) count/no_packets;
    printf("count = %d; throughput[%d] = %f\n", count, l, throughput[l]);
    printf("freeing now...\n");
    free(pkt_holder);
    free(pkt_collision);
    lamda+=0.1;
    l++;
  }

  printf("Sucess: %d\n",count);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is why you should never do:

```
double *lamdas;
lamdas = (float *)malloc(iterations*sizeof(float));
```

This mis-matches and allocated half the expected space. It should be:

```
lambdas = malloc(iterations * sizeof *lambdas);
```

Don't manually repeat the type, it's risky and verbose. "Lock" it to the destination pointer and use `sizeof`.

Also, [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](https://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: Good catch on the type mismatch. I think that using a floating point loop counter may also be a source of problems.

Comment: Just a small correction: use `sizeof(*lambdas)` instead of `sizeof *lambdas`.

Comment: Note the same issue arises with `throughput` but the error is most likely caused by this one. Ironic since the array is allocated and filled but never used.